# is there a way to import all keys inside a package with require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, environment-variables, global-variables

I would like to know if there is a way to import all elements of a package/file without directly naming them
example:

```js
//file1 - things.js
module.exports = {
  thing1:{...},
  thing2:{...},
  thing3:{...}
}
//file2 runner.js

const things = require("./things")
console.log(things.thing1) 
//in this case it imports the things.js and its elements and assigns the variable things,
//but that's not what I want
//I want it to import the native variables from the things.js file without having to pull each one individually
//---
//i know i can import the native variables by pulling them like this:
const { thing1, thing2 } = require("./things")
console.log(thing1, thing2)
//but this is not what I want either, what I want should look like the following example:

const {} = require("./things")
console.log(thing1, thing2, thing3) 
//imporiting all native variables without having to define one by one
```

Comment: no, you can't..

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no.

When using `module.exports`, you're effectively assigning a value to the return of `require`. That value can be any valid JavaScript value, in this particular case, an object. Presently, JavaScript does not have a mechanism for destructuring an object into all of its constituent keys, which is functionally what you're asking for.

In fact, JavaScript has no mechanism at all for ***implicit*** variable declaration, at least not in strict mode. If it doesn't appear in the source code, it's not there.

A hacky way around this could be something like this:

```js
const thing = require('../thing.js');
for (const key in Object.keys(thing)) {
  global[key] = thing[key]; // using "global" here instead of "window" for environment-agnostic code
}
```

This will force all of your exports to be available in the global scope, accessible as if they were declared. However, your editor/IDE will get very upset that it doesn't know where these variables came from, and this is horrific, unrecommendable practice.